# How to parse and regenerate PDF using php

Tags: php, pdftk, pdf-parsing

I want to edit some part of the PDF and regenerates it in the same format after editing. I have tried `pdftk` but it won't allow to edit the readonly labels.i got success to parse the pdf using `Smalot pdf parser` but now i don't know how to again regenerate it in the same format after parsing??

Thanks in advance!!!1

Comment: have you tried http://www.fpdf.org/ ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix : Yes i tried different pdf libraries but my concern is that how to regenerate the pdf in same format as it was. `pdftk`  is something which gives you proper output but it only allows to change the form values in my case it's not the form fields.

Comment: @VasilShaddix : but let me check again the `fpdf`. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: what do you mean by same format ?

Comment: after edit the pdf the format would be same as it was before. i want to edit some things in pdf which will come dynamically and save so user don't have to fill those data.

Comment: fpdf should do that for you. just look up the lib. Its pretty simple and easy to use. best of luck. if you have any trouble, hit me up :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135553/discussion-between-prakash-tank-and-vasil-shaddix).